# Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b) on El Capitan now being rejected

Tags: xcode6, app-store-connect

I am not using beta Xcode software. I have always been able to submit to the app store regardless of mac osx version, as long as I used the latest GM Xcode release. All of a sudden, from what I can tell, a few days ago itunes connect is now failing when submitting for review.

Before you respond by "You cannot use beta software to submit applications to the app store" please read the official copy from Apple.

> Submitting Apps Apps that are created using beta versions of Xcode or
>   that are built for beta versions of operating systems will not be
>   accepted on the App Store and Mac App Store. Apps that you submit
>   should be developed using the **latest version of Xcode from the Mac App
>   Store** and should be **built for publicly available versions of iOS, OS
>   X, and watchOS** — except when GM seeds are available. When a GM Seed of
>   Xcode becomes available, use it to develop your app for submission.
>   When GM seeds of iOS, OS X, or watchOS become available, build your
>   app for these versions.

Nowhere in this text requires you to build **ON** publically released versions of OS X, and has never been the case.

Radars filed #22116787 and #22116676

Comment: Yeah they explicitly stopped 6.4 running on previous betas and I think the release notes for the betas state you can't submit from them.

Comment: Do you know where you read that? I just read the El Capitan Beta 5 release notes and the only thing i could find is a minor mention "Xcode 6.x has known compatibility issues when run on OS X El Capitan. It is strongly encouraged that you use Xcode 7 when running on OS X El Capitan." Strongly encouraged... sure.. but this would then qualify as an apple bug, not a change in policy.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.4 is no longer supported on El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

I can't even launch Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan anymore.